# Unable to manual WIFI Connect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, wifi, wifimanager

Hi we are unable to manual WIFI Connect in Flutter. we are using   wifi_iot: ^0.3.18 package. this packages auto connects to the network but we unable to connect manual WIFI.

i have tried other packages

- wifi_iot: ^0.3.18
- wifi_connector: ^2.0.0